# How to reconfigure single notebook keyboard buttons - remapping?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, button-remapping

Hi can someone help me out: I like to reconfigure a few keyboard buttons, i like the "+" and "-" signs on the num-pad to function as "End" and "Home" keys.

Is sth like this possible on Windows notebook and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [sharpkeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys). As you can see from screenshot below, all you have to do is:

1. Choose a key from the **Map this key (From key):** column, or type a key
2. Choose a key from the **To this key (To key):** column, or type a key
3. Save the change. (Write to registry)

As the change is written to Windows registry, this app doesn't need to be running for the mapping to work.

After making the changes, just **Sign out** and sign back in for the changes to take effect.

[image]